# androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.GridLayout

Tags: java, android, android-activity, androidx

I am getting error

> "Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout cannot be cast to
>   android.widget.GridLayout", in mainActivity.java

```
 GridLayout mygridLayout = findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);

 for(int i=0; i<mygridLayout.getChildCount(); i++)
 {
     ((ImageView) mygridLayout.getChildAt(i)).setImageResource(0);
 }
```

Comment: Either you have to use `AndroidX` library or `Support` library. Add more details about your layout and code

Answer (score 16):

Change

```
import android.widget.gridLayout
```

to

```
import androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout;
```

and your code will work

Answer (score 6):

Use this in the code it will work.

```
androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout mygridLayout = findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);

for(int i=0; i<mygridLayout.getChildCount(); i++){
 ((ImageView) mygridLayout.getChildAt(i)).setImageResource(0);
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks, it worked! :) where did you find this?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `GridLayout` from AndroidX package in your layout.xml and you are importing `Gridlayout` from package `android.widget` in your source code. Use one or the other and make them consistent.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code to this:

```
androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout mygridLayout = (androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);
```

Answer (score 0):

For this, we need to import `"androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout;"` instead of `"android.widget.GridLayout;"`.